# Printing out each line of an input file twice?

Tags: c, file, while-loop, printf

I am writing code which very simply reads in a file and prints out what was in the file appropriately.

I have always struggled with getting such a program to terminate upon end of file and think I've found the appropriate solution, however each line is printing twice in my output, for a reason beyond me.

Here is my main file:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // insure 2 arguments given, one for a.out and one for the test file
    if (argc != 2) {
        // result if request fails
        printf("Requires 2 arguments. Be sure to include test file location\n");
        return 0;
    }

    FILE *fp; //open the file
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    char option;
    int key;
    int i = 0;
    while (fscanf(fp, "%c %d", &option, &key) != EOF) {
        printf("%d\n", key);
    }
}
```

The key is printing twice!

Hopefully this is a simple error I'm just overlooking due to overexposure to  the problem.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the input file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want:

```
fscanf(fp, "%c %d\n", &option, &key);
```

And you also want to check the return value of `fscanf` to make sure it equals 2.

In the first iteration of your loop, the newline is not being consumed.

In the second iteration, the newline is consumed and put in `option`, and the `%d` does not match, and `fscanf` returns 1.  `key` is unchanged which is why it gets printed again.

In the third iteration, `fscanf` finally returns `EOF`.

General rule:  Always check return values to ensure they are what you expect.  (You also violate this rule by failing to check the return from `fopen`.)  At worst it does nothing; at best, it helps you debug problems like this.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Um, I believe I said that.  I also believe adding `\n` to the format string is the fix for the main bug.

Comment: Err..yes, I suppose you did; but the code speaks louder than words and doesn't reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Requires 1 argument - a file name\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *fp; //open the file
    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == 0)
    {
         fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s\n", argv[1]);
         return 1;
    }

    char option;
    int key;
    while (fscanf(fp, "%c %d", &option, &key) == 2)
        printf("%d\n", key);
    return 0;
}
```

Note the changes in error reporting, and in the file reading process.  The code is still probably not quite what you want; you might get the newline after the number after the first line of input stored in `option` after the first line.  Fixing that requires `fgets()` and `sscanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Requires 1 argument - a file name\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *fp; //open the file
    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == 0)
    {
         fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s\n", argv[1]);
         return 1;
    }
    char buffer[1024];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != 0)
    {
        char option;
        int key;
        if (fscanf(fp, "%c %d", &option, &key) == 2)
            printf("%d\n", key);
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Format mismatch on %s", buffer);
            fclose(fp);  // Not 100% necessary here, but tidiness is important
            return 1;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);          // Not 100% necessary here, but tidiness is important.
    return 0;
}
```

Although I closed `fp` before the end, it is not crucial when the program is about to exit, and `return` from `main()` is pretty much equivalent to `exit()`.  If it was in a function other than `main()` though, it is very important to ensure that you free any resource you allocate, such as the file stream `fp`.

*Warning: uncompiled code. Caveat Lector.*